# How to process Json messages from EventHub using the Python SDK?

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm following this example to process messages received from Event Hub:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/examples/eph.py

But, the code does show any code on how to retrieve each message and get to the Json payload?

I have tried the following code (using the Python SDK for Event Hub):

```
async def process_events_async(self, context, messages):
"""
Called by the processor host when a batch of events has arrived.
This is where the real work of the event processor is done.
:param context: Information about the partition
:type context: ~azure.eventprocessorhost.PartitionContext
:param messages: The events to be processed.
:type messages: list[~azure.eventhub.common.EventData]
"""
    for message in messages:
        message_content = json.loads(message.body)

    logger.info("Events processed {}".format(context.sequence_number))
    await context.checkpoint_async()
```

But, I get the following error message on the statement conaining json.loads:

> "2018-09-20 23:13:12,484 azure ERROR Event Processor Error
>   TypeError("the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not
>   'generator'",)"

Can you help me with the code to get to the Json payload of the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working code to get to the JSON payload of the Event Hub messages:

```
for message in messages:
    message_body = list(message.body)
    message_content = json.loads(message_body[0])
```